# Об Архитектуре JS: Страница, которая рендерится с бека по-разному. Как быть?

Tags: javascript

Имеется страница товара в интернет-магазине, на которую выводятся размеры. Однако у доброй половины товаров размеров нет и потому на страницу выводится лишь список филиалов, откуда товар можно забрать.

Логика для страницы товара с размерами: при клике на размер отправляется AJAX и приходят данные о филиалах, в котором есть таковой размер. Помимо всего прочего, при клике на размер, могут изменяться фотографии товара, его цена (НАЗВАНИЕ, ЛОЛ) и прочие характеристики. После клика на размер, из пришедшего JSON формируется html-код (список всех филиалов, у которых есть данный размер) и вставляется в страницу.

Суть в том, что после этого, при клике на филиал будет также отправляться AJAX на сервер и может опять перерисовываться большое количество характеристик.

Все это приводит к разнящейся логике в JS, большому ветвлению и к 1600 строкам javascript'а, а хотелось бы сделать понятный код, а не кучу комментариев.

Сейчас реализация готова, все работает, но есть время на рефакторинг, который очень хочется сделать, потому что пилить новые фичи в будущем в этом файле может быть нереально тяжело.

Подскажите, может есть какая-то архитектурная модель, которую используют вот в таких ситуациях или как быть?

Comment: Если вы принципиально не хотите делать html-код на сервере, то возьмите что-нибудь нормальное вроде React, Vue или Angular с прилагающимися к ним best practices

Comment: К сожалению, не могу интегрировать фреймворки пока что. А по поводу рендеринга исключительно на сервере - суть в том, что размеров может быть 20 штук и рендерить к каждому размеру по 2-3 фотографии, потом все это инициализировать в слайдеры и переключаться между размерами JS-табами - слишком. Страница будет грузиться полчаса.

Comment: Если размеры отображаются не все сразу, то всегда можно подгрузить html-код с сервера позже по необходимости ajax-запросом, я так делаю и вполне доволен)

Comment: @andreymal *всегда можно подгрузить html-код с сервера позже по необходимости ajax-запросом* - а я думал, вы не такой. Шутка :)